# How to write a complex master-detail query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help getting a SQL query running the way I need. I know you SQL gurus will be laughing at this, but I really don't know how to do this :-(
I have a table in the MS-SQL database with the following data

```
A   B       C
10  1001    1001001
10  1001    1001002
10  1001    1001003
10  1001    1001004
10  1002    1002001
10  1002    1002002
20  2001    2001001
20  2001    2001002
20  2002    2002001
```

I want the following Result

```
10
1001
1001001
1001002
1001003
1001004
1002
1002001
1002002
20
2001
2001001
2001002
2002
2002001
```

Comment: Can you please share your tables structures, input and expected output ? Explain the logic behind your result ...

Comment: @user757321 . . . I actually think this is an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using [`grouping sets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and `order by`:

```
select coalesce(c, b, a)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (a), (a, b), (a, b, c) )
order by a,
         (case when b is null then 1 else 2 end),
         b,
         (case when c is null then 1 else 2 end),
         c;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=787c9f9be8218ea41687c2c6dbfcec92) is a db<>fiddle.

Given the nature of your data, you can simplify the `order by` to:

```
order by a, coalesce(b, a), coalesce(c, b, a)
```

Comment: Nice! I was going to offer a union query but grouping sets is a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH items AS (
  SELECT CAST(A AS NVARCHAR) AS item FROM Table
  UNION
  SELECT CAST(B AS NVARCHAR) FROM Table
  UNION
  SELECT CAST(C AS NVARCHAR) FROM Table
)
SELECT *
  FROM items
 ORDER BY item
```